# How do I use an existing sqlite database in my Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, sqlite-net

I have a database from an existing android app that I need to import into my Windows Phone 8 app. Is the only way to do this to create some huge population script to be ran on the first loading of the app?

I am currently using the new sqlite-net-wp8 by Peter Huene as directed by [this blog post](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/working-with-sqlite-in-windows-phone-8-a-sqlite-net-version-for-mobile/#comment-1522). But the examples are all about creating the database, not using an existing one. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/import-an-already-existing-sqlite-database-in-a-windows-8-application/) shows how to copy an existing sqlite database in Windows 8. The ability to do it on a phone is the same.

1) Add the sqlite database into your project and set the type to content in its properties.

2) When your app loads, load the file into a storage file. Then write it back out using the localfolder as the destination.

Answer (score 1):

WP8 only supports local (in local file) databases. 
Check your solution and search for database file. If file does't exist then You can only copy by script.

Comment: That is disappointing. Even WP7 provided the means to copy a database over, even if it was [unduly complicated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: This is actually possible using the link I posted above. I'll expand further in an answer shortly.